# Oracle Sql merge table with multiple where clause and date between and Day week month

Tags: mysql, oracle

```
I have two tables mentioned below  

   Table 1
Pk     Type       EVENTID    TimeStamp                                
1      Audio1          1     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           
2      Video1          1     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           
3      Audio2          2     11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           
4      Video2          2     11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           
5      Audio3          3     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           
6      Video3          3     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           
7      Audio4          4     12-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM           
8      Video4          4     12-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM     

Above is my first table.With audio and video files.    

My second table is     
 Table 2
    Pk    EVENTID      TimeStamp                              Date   
    1        1        11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM          11-JAN-15 
    2        2        11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM          11-JAN-15
    3        3        11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM          11-JAN-15
    4        4        12-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM          12-JAN-15      


I am looking for an output mentioned in the table below.    


Table 3
    Type        Type      EventId           TimeStamp                                Date
    Audio1     Video1      1            11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
    Audio2     Video2      2            11-JAN-15 12.33.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
    Audio3     Video3      3            11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
    Audio4     Video4      4            11-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM           12-JAN-15
```

EventID is unique between two tables. I want to get results on basis of date from Table2 i.e Table2.Date between Date1 and Date2 and also for Day, Week and Month.Is there any possibility to get this result.If there is any please help me.

```
Thanks 
Shyam
```

Comment: Please review the answer given below and let us know if it solved your problem.

Comment: No this query did not solve my problem.Is there any other way..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your comment does not tell _why_ my query did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Upon closer inspection, your query is simpler than it seems because the `TimeStamp` column is the same for the audio and video records for a given `EVENTID`.  So all you really need to do is `JOIN` together the two tables with a `WHERE` restriction and add a new `Type` column.

```
SELECT t1.Type AS Type, CONCAT('Video', t1.EVENTID) AS Type, t1.EVENTID AS EventId,
    t1.TimeStamp AS TimeStamp, t2.Date AS Date
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Pk = t2.Pk
WHERE SUBSTRING(t1.Type, 1, 5) = 'Audio' AND
    t2.Date >= '2015-01-11' AND t2.Date <= '2015-01-12'
```